# Create separate import lib with a subset of a .dll/.so's exports for third-party users (Visual C++, gcc)

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

For my project, a number of users have requested a way to access certain portions of the DLLs it creates. I'd like to build an API for them with header files and a .lib (or Linux equivalent, for the Linux version) that has a specific subset of the functionality. This question is mainly targeted toward Visual C++ because I'm primarily a Windows developer, but the project also has a Linux build so I'd like to know how to do this in Linux as well.

For instance, one of the sub-projects creates a DLL file called foo.dll, which is referenced by a few of the executables built by other sub-projects, and those executables link against foo.lib. The distribution includes foo.dll, but not foo.lib. I want to create foo-subset.lib and foo-subset.h files to distribute to users, so they can easily access selected parts of foo.dll.

Creating the foo-subset.h header itself shouldn't be bad, because I can use comments to decorate which parts of my regular headers I want, and use some post-processing magic after foo.dll is built. But is there a way to use just foo-subset.h's imports to create foo-subset.lib?

I'm assuming at a bare minimum, I need another subproject for this. It would be best if I didn't have to manually create a .def file and keep that updated, especially since this is meant to also have a Linux version and I don't really know how to handle this in gcc either.

Comment: Is your API a C style one of C++? Are there classes you provide for your users?

Comment: Is your code opensource so your users can compile the code themselves? Can you use CMake? Even .dlls on windows are problematic if c++ is involved and the user is using a different compiler.

Comment: You should remember that as long as you provide the clients with `foo.dll`, theoretically all the code is accessible to them through reverse engineering, even if you don't provide the declarations in the header/lib file.

Comment: There will be classes defined in foo-subset.h. The code is not open source. The goal here is to provide some hooks for parts of the .dll/.so that I'd like users to be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

With the Microsoft tools this can be accomplished using the "lib.exe" tool. You can even create import libraries when you don't have source for the DLL.

You can either create a .def file or put symbol names on the lib.exe command line (much like you can when building the library to begin with).

More information can be found at Building an Import Library and Export File)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/building-an-import-library-and-export-file?view=msvc-170]With the Microsoft tools this can be accomplished using the "lib.exe" tool. You can even create import libraries for .DLLs that you don't have source for at all.

More information can be found at [Building an Import Library and Export File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/building-an-import-library-and-export-file?view=msvc-1700).

Comment: So my concern here is: How do I do this in an automated way? I'd prefer not to have to keep and maintain a separate .def file for this. And even if I did have to do it that way, what would be the Linux equivalent so Linux users can import subsets of foo.dll?

Comment: I am not aware of any automated means to have a .lib that only offers some of the symbols exported by a .dll. After all, you have to tell the tool somehow "export this symbol, and that symbol and hey, include this other one too".

Comment: Linux does not have .def files or dlls. It has .so files but they are not exported the same way: [https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Exported-Symbols-of-Shared-Libraries.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Exported-Symbols-of-Shared-Libraries.html)

Comment: If a .def is the only option, I guess I can live with that. From what I'm seeing it doesn't appear I actually need to do anything special with Linux as long as users have the foo.so file.

Comment: As a developer of the `.so` file you can control the visibility of the exported symbols: [https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) and there no .def file or need for one. You provide the header and the .so file.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea - consider placing the classes/functions that you want to expose into a separate namespace. Then you can analyze the symbols in the library with librarian tool `lib.exe` and remove everything that's not in that namespace.

Comment: How would that be done exactly in Windows, and what would the equivalent be in Linux?